# how to see what was request rewritten to by RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have some RewriteRules in my apache htaccess for debugging reasons I would like to see which rule was accepted and what was redirect rewritten to. In access.log there is only request before all rewrites. Where could I check that?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of apache, you want to set `RewriteLogLevel` or the per-module `LogLevel`. Set it higher for more output. There are symbolic names, but I just use integers--0 for none, higher for more. Setting to 9 is insane amount of output.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html